# compiler tries to evaluate unreachable code after constexpr if

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++17, template-meta-programming

I've experimenting with C++17 lately and found this:

```
template<size_t i>
void recurse()
{
    if constexpr(i == 0)
        return;
    return recurse<i - 1>();
}
```

Trying to call `recurse<4>();` will lead to

`fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
         return recurse<i - 1>();`

Adding an else fixes the error:

```
template<size_t i>
void recurse()
{
    if constexpr(i == 0)
        return;
    else
        return recurse<i - 1>();
}
```

Is this a bug? Unfortunately I don't have access to another compiler than gcc 7.3.0 right now.

Comment: size_t is an "unsigned int" type, which means a negative is translated into huge number, that's why maximum 900 exceeds in that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No: isn't a bug.

Both `if constexpr` and `else` are necessary.

In you first version

```
template<size_t i>
void recurse()
{
    if constexpr(i == 0)
        return;
    return recurse<i - 1>();
}
```

the `recurse<i-1>()` is compiled also when `i == 0`, so is generated `recurse<-1>()`, so is generated `recurse<-2>()`, etc.

You need the `else` to link the `return recurse<i-1>()` to `if constexpr (i == 0)` and avoid it's compilation when `i == 0` ending the recursion.

You can try the second version removing `constexpr`

```
template<size_t i>
void recurse()
{
    if (i == 0)
        return;
    else
        return recurse<i - 1>();
}
```

and you should get the same "template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900" recursion error.

Comment: Normally the compiler will remove unreacheable code. Since the result of if constexpr if is known at compile time the compiler also knows that the second return statement is never reached and thus should be able to remove it. On the other hand, the additional else doesn't really hurt ;)

Comment: @HenrikS - As far I know, the compiler *can* remove unreachable code; with `if constexpr` (and a corresponding `else`) *must* remove it. That `else` is necessary to be sure that the unnecessary code is removed.

Comment: @HenrikS The compiler has to determine the observable behaviour of the program, so that it can ensure that it doesn't change it. The `if constexpr` allows it to skip blocks *during* that determination

Answer (score 0):

Same thing on gcc 8.1 and on some other gcc versions too. I think, *static if* needs else branch too, because if you haven't, compiler always generates recurse() call.

Answer (score 0):

max66's answer is just fine, but as someone who has implemented various parsers and even simple compilers over the years let me offer you some more context.

Let's first get this out of the way: It would only be a bug if the standard mandated it (or GCC documented the behavior you want, as a language extension).

However, the standard *cannot* mandate that unreachable code be removed because detecting which code is unreachable is an [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem). This can be trivially proven by reducing it to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Assume that `comp` is a Turing machine computation, `n` is a non-negative integer value (of an unbounded type) and `halts` is a function that executes up to `n` number of iterations of `comp` and returns whether or not a halting state was reached. Now consider the following pseudo-code:

```
if ( halts(comp, n) )
    print "Halted.";
```

Determining whether or not the `print` statement is reachable therefore requires solving the halting problem for `comp` which is an arbitrary Turing machine calculation – not possible.

Now you might say that this is a very contrived reasoning, and has nothing to do with obviously decidable cases such as your example. However, consider that intuitive assumptions about "obviousness" and the wording of the language standard are two very different things. In other words, the committee would need to select a subset of "detectable" cases and carefully specify under which circumstances the implementation is required to detect unreachable code (and, in time, prune the evaluation tree). Compiler vendors would then be obliged to spend a possibly great deal of time implementing these rules. (Remember that software traditionally operates on "hard-coded" logical rules and does not "intuit" its required behavior. Maybe one day we'll have AI compilers that automagically do "the right thing", but we're currently not even close to that.)

Long story short – while such an approach could be taken, resources are limited, and there are simply a great many more important issues to be solved. The inconvenience of needing to be explicit about the branch structure by adding an `else`, in your example, is indeed minor.